# React Navigation v3 Modal does not work with createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React Navigation v3 Modal does not work with createBottomTabNavigator and not sure why. However, `headerMode: 'none'` seems to be working but `mode: 'modal'` is not showing up as modal.

```js
const Addpicture = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Addpicture: {
      screen: Addpicture
    }
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal', // This does NOT work
    headerMode: 'none' // But this works
  }
);

const Navigator =  createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    'My Interviews': {
      screen: MyDatesStack
    },
    'Add Interview': {
      screen: AddDateStack
    },
    'Companies': {
      screen: CompaniesStack
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(Navigator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it doesn't work no matter what I tried.

I solved this problem by following steps below. Let's say you want to open modal when NewModal tab is pressed.

1. Set up your app container by including tabs stack & to be opened modal navigation stack:

```
  const FinalTabsStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: TabNavigator,
      NewModal: NewModalNavigator
    }, {
      mode: 'modal',
    }
  )
```

2. Create app container with that tabs stack per [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html) guide
3. Inside the `TabNavigator` in the `createBottomTabNavigator` return null component for specific tab (NewModal) (to turn off navigation by react-navigator)

```
  const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Feed: FeedNavigator,
    Search: SearchNavigator,
    NewModal: () => null,
    Chat: ChatNavigator,
    MyAccount: MyAccountNavigator,
}
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      mode: 'modal',
      header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        if (routeName === 'NewModal') {
          return <NewModalTab isFocused={focused} />;
        }
      },
    }),
```

4. Handle click manually inside a custom tab component `NewModalTab` with TouchableWithoutFeedback & onPress. Inside NewModalTab component:

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onPress}>
    <Your custom tab component here />
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

5. Once you catch onPress dispatch redux event

```
  onPress = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'NAVIGATION_NAVIGATE', payload: {
      key: 'NewModalNavigator',
      routeName: 'NewSelfieNavigator',
    }})
  }
```

6. Handle dispatched event using [Navigation Service](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html). I'm using `redux-saga` for it

```
  NavigationService.navigate(action.payload);
```

A bit complicated but works.